# How to replace a dependency in ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In the startup.cs we have this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    }
```

And so our Index Razor page can have this:

```
    public IndexModel(IStringLocalizer<Strings> localizer) {
```

I want to wrap the `localizer` in another class and replace it's presence in the IoC container with a singleton of the wrapper.

The problem is that it does not appear possible to retrieve or remove entries from the container while in the `COnfigureServices` method.

Essentially, I want to replace the registered instance provided by the `AddLocalization` call so that I don't need to replace every instance of the wrapper class's injection in the solution.

Is this possible?

Comment: You don't want to inject `localizer ` into every page? just use a static class that has instance of `localizer` in pages?

Comment: Localizer is already injected into every page - I don't want to update every file which contains the reference. I want to create my own wrapper instance using the localizer from the DI container, then replace that localizer with my wrapper instance. This requires removing the existing registered instance.

Comment: So create your own wrapper then inject `IStringLocalizer<Strings> localizer` into wrapper constructor and register the wrapper class in `ConfigureServices` method. Are looking for something like this:  `services.AddSingleton(typeof(WrapperClass), resolver =>
                {
                    
                    
                        var localizer = resolver.GetService<IStringLocalizer<Strings>>();
                        return new WrapperClass(localizer);
                    
                })`

Comment: @mohsen-esmailpour I would, except that would leave the MS localization in the container and I want to replace that registered type with my wrapper so that the places which inject it end up getting mine, hence removing the need to update lots of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem with **Decorator pattern**.

First of all configure the services so that you can access the `StringLocalizer<>` directly. This is for the `MyLocalizer<>` class, because it needs a direct instance of `StringLocalizer<>` type, not the interface (`IStringLocalizer<>`). If you don't register it `MyLocalizer<>` would not get resolved.

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(StringLocalizer<>));
```

Then register the decorator (the dependency that you want to be replaced). **Note** that I assumed `AddLocalization()` is called before this line of code. This is the rule of the DI container; it always resolves the last registered type. So, after this line of code all dependents of `IStringLocalizer<>` will get `MyLocalizer<>` instead of the standard `StringLocalizer<>`.

```
// be careful about using Singleton scope
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStringLocalizer<>), typeof(MyLocalizer<>));
```

**Decorator Implementation:**

Decorator pattern allows you to add extra features to an existing object. Suppose the `IStringLocalizer<T>` object returns a simple string that I need to just make it upper-case.

```
public class MyLocalizer<T> : IStringLocalizer<T>
{
   public MyLocalizer(StringLocalizer<T> original)
   {
      _original = original;
   }

   private readonly StringLocalizer<T> _original;

   // the decorator behavior is the same for all other methods. 
   // But for this particular method it adds a little feature to the original one! Beautiful :)
   public LocalizedString this[string name] =>
      new LocalizedString(name, _original[name].Value.ToUpper());

   public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] =>
      _original[name, arguments];

   public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures) =>
      _original.GetAllStrings(includeParentCultures);

   public IStringLocalizer WithCulture(CultureInfo culture) =>
      _original.WithCulture(culture);
}
```

Now, nothing in your dependent classes will change. They just use `MyLocalizer<T>` instead of MVC's `StingLocalizer<T>`.

Wish that helps!

Comment: My understanding is that the Localizer<T> is registered with the container by the `services.AddLocalization()` call, so I don't get to choose whether it is registered with transient or not. Also, are you saying that registering a singleton with a specified type for an already registered type will cause my singleton to be returned whenever that original type is injected? (In effect, overriding the original registration of the injected type?)

Comment: @MattW The container always gives you the last registered type. I didn't write the `services.AddLocalization()` in my code, I assumed it's written before all this. So you don't need to worry, because in this case the last registered type is `MyLocalizer<>` and the container will give that to your classes. I will edit my answer to make things more clear.